# How can I insert a #defined string into a system() command? (win32)

Tags: c, windows, c-preprocessor

Here is an overly simplified version of what I am trying to do:

```
#define LOGDIRECTORY C:\\logs\\
system("mkdir LOGDIRECTORY");
```

However the preprocessor, instead of swapping out the defined name is not. Instead the system command actually thinks `LOGDIRECTORY` is the name, and thus is shooting me errors when starting the program.

I know it's wrong and there must be something I can do with the `"` marks or other characters to specify what I want, but I can't figure it out. I don't want to hardcode the directory and file names because someone may want to change them in the future and it would be much easier to change a define than the whole function etc.

PS, I am coding this in plain **C**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
#define LOGDIRECTORY C:\\logs\\
#define DEF2STR(x) #x
system("mkdir " DEF2STR(LOGDIRECTORY));
#define LOGDIRECTORY_WITH_QUOTES "C:\\logs\\"
system("mkdir " LOGDIRECTORY_WITH_QUOTES);
```

In C, you can do simple string concatenation by writing two string literals with no operator in between. `"A" "B"` will be converted to `"AB"` at compile time. You can also use this for splitting a long string to multiple lines.

```
printf("a very long "
"string indeed");
```

To convert the define to a proper string, use the pound sign (<kbd>#</kbd>) in a macro or skip the whole thing and include the quotes in the define itself.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is a perfect solution!

Answer (score 1):

If you were compiling with GCC, you would have no choice but to wrap the define with quotes since the final trailing backslash would be interpreted as a line continuation character, and if that does not cause an error on its own, the penultimate backslash would likely raise a error.  However, if you chose to just get rid of the trailing backslash, you'd still need to use two levels of stringification macros, or your syscal would be "mkdir LOGDIRECTORY". See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html

So the above example would become:

```
#define LOGDIRECTORY C:\\logs
#define DEF2STR(x) #x
#define STR(x) DEF2STR(x)
system("mkdir " STR(LOGDIRECTORY));
```